# need regex to read product SKU and other data from filename

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a regex for the format of filename which will look like this;

```
B2B_1111108A20.jpg
B2B_1111108A20_1.jpg
B2B_1111108A20_2_S.jpg
B2B_1111108A20_3_ST.jpg
```

and then doing a preg_match to the split data because I need to read the **SKU** of the product as filename contains it. And after fetching the **SKU** i will do the rest of the logic.

I tried this regex:

```
^B2B_.*(_([0-9]+))?(_([A-Za-z]+))?$
```

It does return the matching file name but the data never gets split with **preg_match** function. Instead I get the whole name back. Where as I am expecting result something like this (depending on what filenames mentioned above):

```
$result[0] = B2B_1111108A20
$result[1] = B2B_1111108A20
$result[2] = _1
$result[3] = 1
```

Comment: Did you try testing your regex in a tool like?: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` to match all strings

Comment: @Nicarus I have tried my regex but not specially on the tool regex101.com

Comment: @Capri82 - The only reason I ask that is because it shows your regex is not returning the matches you are looking for. Without knowing the pattern/exclusions you need for _all_ cases, this may work: `(B2B_)([A-z0-9]*)(_.*)?(?=\.jpg)`. And, as @anubhava mentions, be sure it is a match all.

Comment: @Nicarus  I am afraid I dont have a luxury to use the preg_match_all instead of preg_match. Reason is code is written by someone else and to change I will need to go through a lot of effort which I want to avoid and just want to achieve my result with regex.

Comment: @Capri82 - You may have a problem then: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-returnvalues

Comment: @Nicarus well, that is why I asked that if someone can assist me with the correct regex. Because I have tried it different ways but not getting the desire result.

Comment: @Capri82 - No, I mean that the function you are using simply returns a value whether the regex is found - regardless of how many matches. Read the documentation... it is simply the wrong function for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Nicarus Just updated my question. Do you still think I use the preg_match_all instead?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wy8ISb/1) will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is `.*`. This is greedy, so will basically eat up everything. Since you have `?` for your subgroups, they will essentially be ignored since the quantifier is greedy. Removing it solves part of your problem. The `$` also makes no sense since your lines end with `.jpg`

As for `.*` maybe instead of anything use `[^_.]`

So the overall regex looks like: `^B2B_[^_.]*(_([0-9]+))?(_([A-Za-z]+))?`

https://regex101.com/r/HzZymV/2

Comment: the regex you provided does match with the filenames but the preg_match or preg_match_all function do not return the correct result. E.g. for B2B_1111108A20_1.jpg preg_match returns array[0] = B2B_1111108A20_1, array[1] = _1, array[2] = 1. Which is different then what I want. It is fine if index 1 does not contain the correct name but atleast index 0 should have only the value B2B_1111108A20 for all cases.

Comment: Not possible, index 0 will always be the full regex'd string. If you want only the first part, then make a subgroup of the first part. Which means index 1 will be the part that you want, and everything else will have their indexes pushed by 1. So just change to `(B2B_[^_.]*)`